# Particles collide with first object then die on second collision

Tags: particles

I want particles to collide off one surface (hard object) then die on the second (colliding with water). Both are easy on their own but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish doing both in one particle system. is this possible!?

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't just having one object set up as "Collision" and the other as "Collision (kill particles enabled)" work? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNV6B.gif

Comment: Yep that works. So simple and it still eluded me for about 3 hours. Thank you mate!

Comment: @NicolaSap - Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: @bertmoog sure, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible: collisions are defined per-object, not per-particle system, so you can define as many types of collisions as you want.

Just enable the "Collisions" physics on both objects, checking the "kill particles" box only for the second one.

[image]

If the second object comes from a water/ocean simulation, make sure that the "collision" modifier is the last one on the modifier stack.

[image]

(for clarity, in my example I've checked "Render dead particles")